# Как получить реальный контент, если передана строка?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Если в мой элемент управления (наследник `Usercontrol`) передать контент, то посредством `TheUserControl.Content as FrameworkElement` я могу узнать чем является контент, однако если передана строка, то контент будет типа `string`, хотя строка автоматом преобразуется в `TextBlock` (так показывает визуальное дерево, так показывает Snoop). Вопрос, как мне от `TheUserControl.Content` типа `string` перейти к элементу управления `TextBlock`, который реально используется для отображения строки?

```
<local:MyUserControl Name="TheUserControl">
    контент типа string
</local:MyUserControl>
```

C#:

```
Console.WriteLine(TheUserControl.Content.GetType()); // выводит string, а в визуальном дереве тут TextBlock
```

Приходит в голову `VisualTreeHelper`, но как добраться через него до нужного мне элемента пока не придумал.

Comment: Из такого описания вопроса очень сложно уловить суть. Опишите точнее что Вы делаете и хотите сделать. Приведите проблемный участок кода.

Comment: @Streletz, так понятнее?

Comment: @Streletz, хотя там в последнем предложении все понятно должно быть в связке с названием темы.

Comment: Все равно совсем непонятно. С UserControl и FrameworkElement все ясно, но почему вдруг, передавая string вы принимаете TextBlock? Принимайте string и пишите в textbox отдельно или передавайте  и принимайте TextBlock и из него уже извлекайте Text. Но, очевидно, что я все таки не понимаю вопроса. Попробуйте разбить на части и переформулировать. Отвечая на заголовок вопроса: строка (string) -это базовый тип C# и никакого реального контента, кроме самих себя, экземпляры этого типа не содержат.

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev, нет нет нет. Все не так. Я не знаю, как это переформулировать. Просто создайте кнопку, передайте в качестве контента строку `Content="text"`, запустите приложение и посмотрите в визуальном дереве (например при помощи Snoop) что получится. Вы увидите там `TextBlock`, хотя вы сами его не создавали, потому что строка не является визуальным элементом. Вот этот `TextBlock` мне и нужен.

Comment: Ну вот, а говорите не знаете как переформулировать.  Теперь намного понятнее.

Comment: Теперь совсем другое дело (минус снял).

Comment: @Streletz, так и вы пишите в следующий раз, что именно не понятно. Формулировка сложная сама по себе. Я то сам себя понял. )

Answer (score 2):

нашел решение.

```
private FrameworkElement findVisualContent(DependencyObject obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        var current = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        var vc = current as ContentPresenter;
        if (vc != null && !(vc is ScrollContentPresenter))
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(vc) == 1)
                return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(vc, 0) as FrameworkElement;

        var rec = findVisualContent(current);
        if (rec != null)
            return rec;
    }
    return null;
}
```

В функцию передаем элемент, контент которого хотим найти.

Answer (score 1):

Этот TextBlock создаётся ContentPresenter в процессе инициализации его содержимым. Не исключено, что Snoop не вполне корректно определяет этот элемент как TextBlock и на самом деле он всё тот же ContentPresenter... И да,  вы пытаетесь залезть в шаблон элемента управления и копать нужно в этом направлении. (я, честно говоря не встречал описания возможности получения доступа к элементам составляющим шаблон элемента управления )

На мой взгляд тут либо как уже было предложено: создавать явно TextBlock и передавать его в качестве конента либо редактировать шаблон кнопки в котором ContentPresenter заменить на TextBlock и пробовать вытаскивать его через Button.Content через приведение типов. 
PS: Насчёт второго варианта не уверен.

Comment: Snoop все отображает корректно. К тому же с ним согласен `VisualTreeHelper` и Visual Life Tree. `ContentPresenter` не смог бы отобразить строку. Для ее отображения он создает `TextBlock`. Сам создает. Мне этого делать не нужно.

Comment: Про Snoop было всего лишь предположение т.к. механизм с помощью которого он получает дерево объектов мне неизвестен. По поводу ContentPresenter и создания им строки я собственно так и написал... А насчёт создания textblock'a -это, как мне кажется, упрощает (вы же смогли найти способ, т.к показали его существование, в чём я сомневался) процесс доступа к данному элементу...

Comment: Это упрощает процесс доступа, но усложняет процесс инициализации. В каком месте я должен его создать?

Comment: Всё зависит от конкретной задачи. Если вы там ожидаете именно текстбокс и ничего кроме, то прям в XAMLe и создавайте: <Button> <TextBlock x:Name="TextOnButton">Text</TextBlock> </Button>

Если там может быть что-то ещё, но вы собираетесь выполнять некоторое действие только если там окажется текст бокс то да, ваш вариант наиболее приемлем....

Comment: Я там ничего не ожидаю. Я понятия не имею что другой программист добавит в контекст: строковую переменную, или текстбокс, или картинку.

Comment: Ну в таком случае ваш вариант предпочтителен...